# jquery remove form input field

Tags: jquery, forms, xhtml, input

Okay I'm a newbie to jQuery and am getting stuck on `.remove()` after doing a click

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.remove_group').click(function(){
    var remove_group_name = $(".test").val();
      $("#group_users["+remove_group_name+"][]").remove();
  });
});
```

HTML form:

```
<input type="text" class="test" name="group_users[test][]" id="group_users[test][]" value="test"> <a href="#" class="remove_group" id="test">Remove Group</a>
```

I want the "Remove Group link" when clicked remove the input field, all I get when I do click it is the webpage moving to the top...

the only warning on the page is: `Expected attribute name or namespace but found ']'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your IDs contains illegal characters (refer to lonesomeday's answer).
Now if you always have the link next to the input, you can write something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/qDqfG/)

One more thing, about when clicking the link the pages scroll to the top, this is because you are not preventing the default *LINK* behavior by using either:
`e.preventDefault;` or `return false;`

Comment: so I did that and wanted to add on to your code: http://jsfiddle.net/nictrix/sPNtv/ - I'm adding a new field, but am unable to use the remove link from your code, any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out with the .live method, see the link for the update

Answer (score 2):

IDs in HTML documents cannot contain square brackets (`[]`).  From the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Practically, you should limit yourself to letters, digits, hyphens and underscores.

Comment: thank you, I was just copying what the name value was showing in the input field for consistency sake, I gave you a plus one because of the question, but ifaour gave me the final answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the debugger and make sure the selector before ".remove();" is actually finding something.  Most likely, it is incorrect.  (Why does it have empty "[]" at the end?)

Answer (score 0):

Try Debugger :

- Why class name and value is same